# How to prove Number of solutions to $e^{-x}=x^2-5x+1$ is $3$ without Graphical approach

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, systems-of-equations, quadratics

How to prove Number of solutions to the Equation  $$e^{-x}=x^2-5x+1$$ is $3$ without Graphical approach

My Try:

I considered a Function $$f(x)=(x^2-5x+1)e^x-1$$

I used $$f(-1) =\frac{7-e}{e} \gt 0$$

$$f(-2)=\frac{15-e^2}{e^2}\gt 0$$

But after this essentially we have to use calculator to find $e^n$ value

Can i have any best approach?

Comment: If you want to show that it's exactly $3$, then you probably have to use derivatives or something. If you only want to show that it's _at least_ $3$, then the intermediate value theorem is enough. Also, I would personally have preferred $g(x)=x^2-5x+1-e^{-x}$, but that doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your $f(x)$, $f'(x)=(x^2-3x-4)e^x$ which has zeros exactly at $4,-1$. Look at the values $\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x),f(-1),f(4),\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$. Checking sign changes (which can be done without a calculator) will allow you to apply the intermediate value theorem to get a lower bound on the number of roots. On the other hand Rolle's theorem will provide an upper bound on the number of roots, and the two will turn out to be the same.